# IMCE not showing files in directory

Tags: files

I inherited a site that has all images in directory stored in `/sites/all/images/`, rather than `/sites/default/files/images/`.

I installed the modules [CKEditor - WYSIWYG HTML editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) and [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/IMCE) image/file uploader and browser (configured correctly), then set a custom file path `/sites/all/images/`.

However, when I go to insert an image into the page, *IMCE file browser* loads and shows the directories on the left-hand side, but it lists the directory as being EMPTY when the directory is actually full of images.

I don't want to move the directory to `/sites/default/files/images/` because I don't want to break all the image links currently in the site's content.

Can anyone tell me how to get *IMCE* to recognize the files in the directory and allow me to insert them into content?

Comment: Did you set up a profile at  Admin >> Configuration >> Media >> IMCE?

Comment: Yup, did that.  Made my own profile and entered the custom path mentioned in my question....simply not working.. triple checked at this point.

Comment: What do you have in the directory path field? I was having some issues and putting a single dot "." there helped (it points to **this location** as opposed to two dots which takes you up the directory tree). However in my case I was getting a "There is no valid directory..." error and my files were supposed to go to the default location. Shot in the dark, but maybe try './sites/all/images'? Path configs can be weird. ;-)

Comment: Not a problem on my end... its known bug with IMCE, that they claim was fixed in the version of the module that I have, but obviously...that's not true. [Read About It](https://www.drupal.org/node/1099994) its a simple site, with no other users, so I simply re-uploaded all the files through IMCE, now they appear.

Comment: I am in the same situation but I can add file througt IMCE and see them. ONly files that my user add. That why I think it's a permission issue. I do not figured it out at this moment but check your folders permission or Drupal's roles maybe.. 

Personnaly I use the './sites/all/images' path to make users arriving in the right folder. That's not really changin somehting with our issue.